# Cannot reach the bearing adjustment nut on rear wheel

Tags: bearings, sprocket

I have a Mt. bike with Shimano STX RC components.  I cannot reach the nut and lock nut to adjust the bearing tension.  Any ideas how to make an adjustment so I can reach it?
[image]

[image]

Also, How do I tell if my rear sprockets need to be replaced.  Can anybody see it it needs to from the picture?

Comment: You have to remove your casete to have enough space to adjust a bearing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9Oek25xKJ0  The cassette looks OK to me.  Torque it back down to spec.

Comment: I have tried taking off the cassette but it is the freewheel that won't allow me to reach the adjustment nuts.

Comment: Show a pic.  You don't have both a cassette and freewheel.  You have freewheel or a cassette and a freehub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could adjust the other end instead, so long as the cassette locknut is already tight against the cone (if it isn't, take the cassette off and do that first).

http://sheldonbrown.com/cone-adjustment.html:
"For cassette hubs, or conventional rear hubs that I want to adjust without removing the freewheel, I use a thin 15 mm wrench and the two 17's.

To loosen this type of hub, I usually do have to loosen the left locknut from its cone, loosen the cone, then re-tighten the locknut. To tighten it, the two 17's on the locknuts do the job quickly and easily."

Comment: It seems like the bearing adjustment nuts on the cassette side should be accessible.  There is no way to reach them with a wrench once everything is tight as the are recessed inside the freewheel cup.  I realize I could lock the 2 nuts together and then adjust the other side but it seems like something is wrong that I am not able to reach them once everything is tight.

Comment: No, it's normal that you can't: 
http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment http://www.madegood.org/bikes/repair/adjust-a-cup-and-cone-rear-hub/ http://bikemagic.com/how-to/mountain-bike-maintenance/adjust-your-cones.html http://roadcyclinguk.com/how-to/maintenance/how-to-service-cup-and-cone-hubs.html/8

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the cassette you will need a cassette removal socket/tool. The nut you are trying to reach is the hub bearing lock nut. If there is no hub play it should not be wrenched on. The tool/socket can be purchased from Park Tools or at any bike shop.